# pyspark: merge two payload fields based on field ingested_at while joining two dataframes in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframe below.

df1:

| txn_id | amount | x | orderStatus | ingested_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | - | PENDING | 1652265268576 |
| 2 | 200 | - | FAILURE | 1652265283215 |

df2:

| txn_id | amount | y | orderStatus | ingested_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 150 | - | SUCCESS | 1652265283215 |
| 2 | 200 | - | SUCCESS | 1652265268576 |

Both the dataframes have different schema(as in above example one has col x and another has col y, there are more such different column.)

when joining these two dataframe on field txn_id, I am getting duplicate columns such as amount and orderStatus, ingested_at.

when joining these two dataframes, what I want is to merge these payload such that fields amount, orderStatus should be picked from dataframe row which has greater ingested_at, rest of the field can be picked from df1.

for example in above case the result should be something like that:

joined_df:

| txn_id | amount | x | y | orderStatus | ingested_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 150 | - | - | SUCCESS | 1652265283215 |
| 2 | 200 | - | - | FAILURE | 1652265283215 |

the values of fields amount, orderStatus is picked where ingested_at has greater value.

in java I have done something like that but not sure how to do that in pyspark.

```
        JavaPairRDD<String, Tuple2<TxnDateS3Model, TxnDateS3Model>> joinedResult = level2PairRdd.join(captureNotifyPairRdd);
    JavaPairRDD<String, TxnDateS3Model> l2joinedCaptureNotifyPairRdd = joinedResult
            .mapToPair(joinResult -> new Tuple2<>(joinResult._1, DataUtils.mergePayload(joinResult._2._1, joinResult._2._2)));
```

mergePayload class have the logic to merge two payload based on their ingestion_time.

Anyone have any idea how it can be achieved in pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more optimal solution of this but from the info you have given, I am assuming that both `df1` and `df2` have the same schema

1. Start by doing a union of both DataFrames:
2. Rank the rows to get the latest record for each value of `txn_id`
3. Discard the rows where the rank indicates that row is not the latest record

The implementation would look something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

final_df = df1 \
    .unionByName(df2) \
    .withColumn('row_num', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('txn_id').orderBy(desc('ingested_at')))) \
    .filter(col('row_num') > 1) \
    .drop('row_num')
```

`final_df` will contain the latest record for each `txn_id`

Comment: thanks for providing your thoughts. FYI both the dataframe have different schema as  already mentioned above one has col 'x' and another has col 'y'. Also I don't want union(all record from both) rather I want intersaction of row with same txn_id (basically inner join).  All I want orderStatus should be picked from latest (which has ingested_at greater value.)